# Len Function for Multiple Cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

need a character count function like the len function but I need it to take a range (i.e A1:D22). What do you suggest I use? I'm looking for something other than fill down on the len function across multiple columns and rows and then sum it all. I'm trying to do it with one function. This is to use it as a check value.

Comment: This is not a programming question. Better suited to Super User

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand well, you can use the following array formula:

=SUM(LEN(A1:D22))

Note: press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to enter the formula (because this is array formula)

Comment: +1. Also to avoid need for CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER you could use SUMPRODUCT in place of SUM, i.e. =SUMPRODUCT(LEN(A1:D22))

Comment: @barry didn't know that. I will have to try that

Comment: My my, aren't these two Dans helping each other remarkably nicely?!

Comment: Absolutely amazing. I mean, of all the usernames to pick...!

Answer (score 6):

You can use an array formula

```
=SUM(LEN(A1:D22))
```

Enter and hit control + shift + Enter